# Find email address between specific substring and semicolon

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, email-address

I'd like to extract the email address frim this string:

```
ezeze smtp.mailfrom=mymail@gmail.com; rerer
```

How should I write my regex in `preg_match` to find the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex pattern:

`(?<=mailfrom=)[^;]+(?=;)`

```
(?<=mailfrom=) // assert 'mailfrom=' on the left
[^;]+          // 1 or more characters not ';'
(?=;)          // assert ';' on the right
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SgDXlJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any capture groups or lookarounds (which will slow down the regex engine).

Find/Match the starting marker substring, then "forget" those characters with `\K`, then match all non-semicolon characters in a greedy fashion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ON9Rg))

```
$string = 'ezeze smtp.mailfrom=mymail@gmail.com; rerer';

echo preg_match(
         '/smtp\.mailfrom=\K[^;]+/',
         $string,
         $match
     )
     ? $match[0]
     : 'no email address';
```

Output:

```
mymail@gmail.com
```